# Adjoining elements in subextension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Suppose $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is an extension of degree 10 and $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq E_1 \subseteq L$ with $[E_1: \mathbb{Q}]$ = 2 and $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq E_2 \subseteq L$ with $[E_2: \mathbb{Q}]$ = 5. Also, let $x_1 \in E_1$ and $x_2 \in E_2$. Must there exist $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $Q(\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2) = L$?

Clearly, if $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ then the answer to the question is no, but what if this is not the case?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1\in E_1$, $x_2\in E_2$ and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in\Bbb{Q}$. Set $\alpha:=\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2$ and $K:=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $d:=[K:\Bbb{Q}]$.

If $x_1\in\Bbb{Q}$ then $\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2\in E_2$ and hence $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2)\subset E_2$, so in particular $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2)\neq L$. Similarly if $x_2\in\Bbb{Q}$ then $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2)\neq L$. So if $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2)=L$ then necessarily $x_1,x_2\notin\Bbb{Q}$.

Now suppose $x_1,x_2\notin\Bbb{Q}$, set $\alpha:=\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2$ and $d:=[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha):\Bbb{Q}]$. Then $d\mid10$, so $d\in\{1,2,5,10\}$.

If $d=1$ then $\alpha\in\Bbb{Q}$, which implies $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$.

If $d=2$ then there exist $u,v\in\Bbb{Q}$ such that $\alpha^2+u\alpha+v=0$, which is equivalent to
$$\alpha_2^2x_2^2+(2\alpha_1\alpha_2x_1+u\alpha_2)x_2+\alpha_1^2x_1^2+u\alpha_1x_1+v=0.$$
If $\alpha_2\neq0$ then this shows that $x_2$ is a root of a quadratic polynomial with coefficients in $E_1$. In particular this implies $[E_1(x_2):E_1]\leq2$ and hence $[E_1(x_2):\Bbb{Q}]\leq4$. But $E_2\subset E_1(x_2)$ and $[E_2:\Bbb{Q}]=5$, a contradiction. So $d=2$ implies $\alpha_2=0$.

If $d=5$ then an entirely analogous argument shows that $\alpha_1=0$.

Hence by exhaustion, if $x_1\notin E_1$ and $x_2\notin E_2$, then for *any* nonzero $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in\Bbb{Q}$ we have
$$\Bbb{Q}(\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2)=L.$$

Comment: Can you please explain why if $d=1$ then $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = 0$?

Comment: Also, how can you say that $E_2 \subseteq E_1(x_2)$ and finally: what would you do if the field extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$ were, for instance, 2 and 3? Thanks

Comment: If $d=1$ then $\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2=q$ for some $q\in\Bbb{Q}$, so
$$\alpha_2x_2=q-\alpha_1x_1\in\Bbb{Q}(x_1)=E_1,$$
where clearly $\alpha_2x_2\in E_2$. Because $E_1\cap E_2=\Bbb{Q}$ it follows that $\alpha_2x_2\in\Bbb{Q}$. Because $x_2\notin\Bbb{Q}$ it follows that $\alpha_2=0$.

Comment: Because $\Bbb{Q}\subset E_1$ it follows that $\Bbb{Q}(x_2)\subset E_1(x_2)$, and $\Bbb{Q}(x_2)=E_2$.

Comment: If the degrees were $2$ and $3$ then similar arguments would work.

Comment: Could you explain how to exclude $d=3$ when the degrees are 2 and 3? I understand that $d \neq 1$ and $d \neq 2$

Comment: To me it looks like you are using $d*[E_1 : \mathbb{Q}] < [E_2 : \mathbb{Q}]$ or the other way around, but this only works if $d$ is small enough.

Comment: @AndreasDahlberg I'm using divisibility of the degrees; for the tower of fields $\Bbb{Q}\subseteq E_2\subseteq E_1(x_2)$ the degrees of the extensions satisfy
$$[E_1(x_2):\Bbb{Q}]=[E_1(x_2):E_2]\cdot[E_2:\Bbb{Q}].$$
Plugging in the values I find in my answer then yields
$$4\geq[E_1(x_2):\Bbb{Q}]=[E_1(x_2):E_2]\cdot5,$$
a contradiction.

Comment: @AndreasDahlberg And the inequality can be made more precise; it comes from the tower of fields $\Bbb{Q}\subset E_1\subset E_1(x_2)$, in which the degrees satisfy
$$[E_1(x_2):\Bbb{Q}]=[E_1(x_2):E_1]\cdot[E_1:\Bbb{Q}]=[E_1(x_2):E_1]\cdot2.$$
So even if $[E_2:\Bbb{Q}]=3$ then by the same argument we get
$$2\cdot[E_1(x_2):E_1]=[E_1(x_2):\Bbb{Q}]=[E_1(x_2):E_2]\cdot3,$$
a contradiction because $[E_1(x_2):E_1]\leq2$.

Comment: But if $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is of degree 6 and the degrees of the subfiels over $\mathbb{Q}$ are 2 and 3 then the possible value of $d$ are 1, 2, 3 and 6. Using your argument I can exclude $d=1$ and $d=2$ but I dont think it works with $d=3$. What do you think?

Comment: @AndreasDahlberg I agree; the argument does not hold if the degrees are not coprime, and in fact such $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in\Bbb{Q}$ need not exist in that case.

Comment: The degrees 2 and 3 are coprime in this case...Also, in the original question I posted I am still a bit sceptical to how you can exclude $d=5$. Can you explain that one more?

Comment: Do you have an example in mind when you say that such $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ need not exist?

Comment: It depends strongly on how you then phrase the question; if $d_1=[E_1:\Bbb{Q}]$ and $d_2:=[E_2:\Bbb{Q}]$ and $d:=[L:\Bbb{Q}]$ you can ask about either $d=d_1d_2$ or $d=\operatorname{lcm}(d_1,d_2)$.

Comment: Nevertheless, I don't see how in the original question I posted you can exclude the case $d=5$. Also, do you have an example in mind where there need not to be such $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$?